# If conjugacy classes and centralizer intersect nontrivially then $G$ is solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any nonsolvable finite group $G$ with the property that 
$$|x^G\cap C_G(x)|>1 $$ for all $1\neq x \in G$.

Comment: It's true in $A_5$ (the smallest nonsolvable group).

Comment: Thanks for counter example. Is it easy to show?

Comment: $(1,2)(3,4)$ is conjugate to $(1,3)(2,4)$, $(1,2,3)$ to $(1,3,2)$, and $(1,2,3,4,5)$ to $(1,5,4,3,2)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Thanks .